# SQLite LINQ Provider Data Context

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sqlite

I am trying to get LINQ to work with SQLite in C# .NET

I downloaded http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.92.0/sqlite-netFx451-setup-bundle-x86-2013-1.0.92.0.exe  and it has an assembly in it:

System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll

How can I get the LINQ provider working? How do I setup a data context? I have looked at many Google search results to no avail.

Comment: See also this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470583/creating-database-using-datacontext-and-system-data-sqlite-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 11):

[LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) is just a specification. It requires an implementation (aka a provider) to actually work. Examples of implementations include [LINQ to Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397919.aspx), [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx), and [Entity Framework](http://msdn.com/data/ef).

The `System.Data.SQLite.Linq` assembly contains SQLite's Entity Framework provider. A while ago, I wrote a blog post on how to get started. See [Entity Framework on SQLite](http://www.bricelam.net/2012/10/entity-framework-on-sqlite.html).

Comment: There was no references to EF in question. Likely author is trying to use Linq-to-SQL, which is different technique.

Comment: -1 because your answer didn't talk about using LINQ with SQLite.

Comment: @JohnJesus The referenced blog post does under the *Start Coding* section.

Comment: Ah, OK.  I'll remove my downvote if you explain in your answer why we need EF to use LINQ on SQL.  I had the same question as the OP and your answer did not really help me.

Comment: Thanks @JohnJesus, I've enhanced my answer.

Comment: Cool.  I get the idea now.